# PIP install request RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I am new to Python and am facing the below issue.

When I am trying to install the 'request' module by using command `PIP install request`, I got the error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
C:\users\sandeep_kumar39\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-gzzphx\setupfiles\
```

The Python version is 2.7.12.

And I already upgraded the distribution package by using command `pip install --upgrade distribute`.

And upgraded the pip version too by using command `pip install --upgrade pip`

Complete output of error:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install request
Collecting request
  Using cached request-0.0.12.tar.gz
Collecting get (from request)
  Using cached get-0.0.20.tar.gz
Collecting post (from request)
  Using cached post-0.0.12.tar.gz
Collecting setupfiles (from request)
  Using cached setupfiles-0.0.16.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\sandeep_kumar39\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-3gsgdg\setupfiles\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        from setupfiles import setup
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
            File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setupfiles # nopep8
      File "setupfiles.py", line 11, in <module>
        dirname = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
      File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 215, in dirname
        return split(p)[0]
      File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 180, in split
        d, p = splitdrive(p)
    RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\sandeep_kumar39\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-3gsgdg\setupfiles\
```

Comment: give the full output of the error and the line that you execute, it will help

Comment: i have edited the question with complete output error.

Comment: Do you actually mean to install [request](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/request) and not [request**s**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)?

Comment: Yes..i want to install request

Comment: Candidate canonical question: *[Python error when attempting to install 'request' package using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930315/)*

Comment: It might have been part of [an injection attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440240/getting-this-error-while-installing-the-request-module-of-python?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment134786828_76440240).

Comment: One guide that contains the typo is *[New and Improved Mac OS Tutorial, Part 1 (The Basics)](https://passthroughpo.st/new-and-improved-mac-os-tutorial-part-1-the-basics/)*. But it is probably not the one used in this case. From *[Improving risks and consequences against typosquatting on pypi](https://discuss.python.org/t/improving-risks-and-consequences-against-typosquatting-on-pypi/5090)*.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be due to [a bug](https://github.com/russianidiot/setupfiles.py/issues/6) in recent versions of [`setupfiles`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setupfiles), upon which [`request`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/request) depends.  You can work around this by first installing version 0.0.14 of setupfiles with `pip install setupfiles==0.0.14` before trying to install `request`.

Comment: Thanks..its installed now :)

Comment: The first link is broken (404).

Comment: A bug? You don't say. It is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748121/i-am-trying-to-install-setupfiles-package-from-pip/52032994#52032994) (my emphasis): *"...a dependency on a package which might have been* ***put in PyPi maliciously"***. The blog post link is also broken, but its title was probably *"What is the story behind russianidiot on PyPI?"*. The larger issue is: *[PyPI Python repository hit by typosquatting sneak attack](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2017/09/19/pypi-python-repository-hit-by-typosquatting-sneak-attack/)*. It is a problem to this day. -

Comment: cont' - [Gibson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Now) talked about it in February 2023 ([episode 912](https://twit.tv/shows/security-now/episodes/912)).